# Create a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to create a panda series that contains the first ‘n’ natural numbers and their respective squares. The first ‘n’ numbers should appear in the index position by using manual indexing

Can someone please share a code with me

Comment: If you want to ask a question on SO, it should be specific, targeted and contained. What you are asking for is a code-writing service, something for which you really ought to pay people. If you are trying to learn to code, most people here are ready, willing and able to give up their free time and energy to provide support. That you have just posted a problem statement and a request for code suggests that you are not interested in learning and feel entitled to ask people to do this for you. Where possible, I endeavour to report questions like this so as not to encourage them.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with `**` for squares:

```
n = 5
s = pd.Series(np.arange(n) ** 2)
print (s)
0     0
1     1
2     4
3     9
4    16
dtype: int32
```

If want omit `0`:

```
n = 5
arr = np.arange(1, n + 1)
s = pd.Series(arr ** 2, index=arr)
print (s)
1     1
2     4
3     9
4    16
5    25
dtype: int32
```